# How do I specify a single quotation mark in a if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, format-specifiers

```
if(ch == ''')
{
   word_len++;
}
```

How do I specify that when `ch` is equal to `'` it adds one to `word_len`? It seems that I am unable to specify it by just using the code above.

Answer (score 6):

You can use escape sequence `'\''`.

```
if(ch == '\'')
{
   word_len++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the single quote. E.g.

```
if ( ch == '\'' )
```